# Putting a postback on a group of buttons triggers multiple postbacks

Tags: jquery

I got a table which contains a button in each row. I want to write a value to a hidden field and trigger a postback when I click any of those buttons:

```
    $('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class="myClass"]').live('click', function (event) { 
        id = $(event.target).parent().parent().find('td:first').text();
        $('[id$=' + hidReturnData + ']').val(id);
        dialog.dialog("close");
        __doPostBack($(btnTarget).attr('name'), '');
    });
```

Unfortunately the postback is triggered multiple times when I click any button - and this results in an issue in my asp-page.

Comment: can you share the html code plz

Comment: add event.stopPropagation()

Comment: @RRR: This is too much code to paste. event.StopPropagation() doesn't work.

Comment: hmmm instead of live use `.on`... also element might  been attached the event handler twice or many times (if the event fires many times) in the code. Probably you are creating the element dynamically. So each time you click on the element , the event handler fires each time it has been bound to the element.

Comment: instead of  `$('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class="myClass"]').live('click', function (event) { ` use  `$('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class="myClass"]').off('click').on('click', function (event) { `

Comment: I'm currently limited to jquery 1.6 and there is no on ;-)

Comment: not sure but you can try using `bind()` instead of `on()` and `unbind()` instead of `off()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from

`$('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class="myClass"]').live('click', function (event) {`

to

`$('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class="myClass"]').one('click', function (event) {`

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you in getting the click event for the button you want

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(e){
    console.log("click",e);
});
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t01nkqf/) here
You can apply your logic to retrieve the value from your hidden element.

Comment: I can't see any console output.

Comment: In the fiddle you are talking..?

Comment: I added it to my code getting three times the same line: f.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timesStamp: x, jQuery1620...: true, which: 1...}

Comment: Yes, in the fiddle. In my code I just used console.log(event)

Comment: it's working for me on the fiddle. SIngle console for single button click.

Comment: can u add your html code for some more help in case u want.

Comment: I tried that using jsfiddle (where I didn't even get an error) and jsbin (which tells me script error line 0): https://jsbin.com/mocaxocipe/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.live()` use `.on()`... also element might have  attached the event handler twice or many times (if the event fires many times) in the code. Probably you are creating the element dynamically. So each time you click on the element , the event handler fires each time it has been bound to the element.

**Instead of**

`$('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class‌​="myClass"]').live('click', function (event) {`

**use**

```
$('#tblSearchDataSource').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('input[class‌​="myClass"]').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
```